# Update Javascript with results from Python script

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

Update Javascript with results from Python script.

I want to update my Javascript script with Python script in `Flask`.

I get a value from my `Python`
script, and want to pass it to or update Javascript.
But can 't figure out how in `Flask`.

The following is my Javascript that I need to update:

```
events: {
load: function() {

// set up the updating of the chart each second
var series = this.series[0];
setInterval(function() {
var x = (new Date()).getTime();

// Value from Python script (DataFrame)
var y = Math.random() * 100;
series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                      }, 5000);
                  }
              }
```

Here, I am passing random values but I want to pass the value from my Python script.
My Python script would be like the following:

```
import MySQLdb
import pandas.io.sql as sqlio

host = "~~~"  # Public
port = 1111
username = "aa"
password = "aaa"
database = "aaaa"

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=host,
                       user=username,
                       passwd=password,
                       db=database,
                       port=port)


qry1 = """
~~
"""

df = sqlio.read_sql(qry1, conn)
df['count'][0] # return some number in Python
```

function members.
I know you won'
have get

Comment: So you would like to have the javascript in the client browser retrieve information from your python script on your server?  Or do you want the value from Python to already be in the javascript script that you send to the client?

Comment: I want to retrieve the value from Python and send it to Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm guessing correctly, you want the javascript code to have a number in it which is generated by a python script.  If you're using Flask, then you're probably using Jinja2, right?

When the page with said javascript is requested and you send it back with render_template(), you can pass a keyword argument to render_template containing that value, and then in the template, you can "echo" that variable's value into the javascript.  For example,if you had the pertinent javascript in template page.html in your templates directory, and had a python function to compute the value called `compute_value`

```
@app.route("/page")
def page():
    value = compute_value()
    return render_Template('page.html', value = value)
```

Then in page.html, you could have this

```
var y = {{ value }}
```

So in a sense you're generating javascript code from python with Jinja2.